# what's the computational complexity of finding maximum common subconfiguration between several subgraph?

Tags: graph, tree, complexity-theory, subgraph

given a set of subgraphs {G1,G2...,Gn} and another set {K1,K2...,Km}. Each G or K is a acyclic tree. Total vertices number in  {G1,G2...,Gn} and {K1,K2...,Km} are equal. So, what's the computational complexity of finding maximum common subconfiguration between {G1,G2...,Gn} and {K1,K2...,Km}. In addition, the search begin at the center node of tree (root of tree) using DFS, if the edge is not equal the search of this branch will stop.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaccT.png)

I think the computational complexity is O(n^2) between only 2 subgraphs. And i dont know what it is between several subgraphs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.